# how to implement 3 same images and 1 different image in 4 image views in android?

Tags: android, image, random

Sorry everyone i'm new in android programming.

I have a game and it consist of number of images in an array. I want to show 3 same images and 1 different image in 4 image views, and if the answer is correct and the player find the different image  it will loop and random again. Please anyone provide me with an example.

```
Random random = new Random( System.currentTimeMillis() );
int next = random.nextInt( 23 ) + 1;

int[] imageViews = {R.id.A,R.id.B,R.id.C,R.id.D };

int[] img = new int[] {R.drawable.img1,R.drawable.img2,R.drawable.img3,R.drawable.img4,
        R.drawable.img5,R.drawable.img6,R.drawable.img7,R.drawable.img8,
        R.drawable.img9,R.drawable.img10};

int [] ansImg = new int[]{R.drawable.aimg1,R.drawable.aimg2,R.drawable.aimg3,R.drawable.aimg4,
    R.drawable.aimg5,R.drawable.aimg6,R.drawable.aimg7,R.drawable.aimg8,
        R.drawable.aimg9,R.drawable.aimg10};

private void allImage() {
     ImageView a= (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.A);
     ImageView b= (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.B);
     ImageView c= (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.C);
     ImageView d= (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.D);
}

    public void randomImage(){
    List<Integer> generated = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (int i = 0; i < imageViews.length; i++) {
        int v = imageViews[i]-1;
        int vs = imageViews[i]-3;

        if ( generated.contains( next ) ) {
            generated.add( next );
            ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById( v );
            ImageView ivs = (ImageView) findViewById( vs );
            iv.setImageResource( img[next] );
            ivs.setImageResource(ansImg[next]);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: not getting what you want to do, also please add your code

Comment: ok sir.. i'll provide ..

Comment: What do you mean by "if i got the different image it will random"
From your code i get that you want to show images in 4 different imageViews, and that one image is Supposed to be different form the others.
But there is nothing handling any kind of userInput

Comment: sorry sir .. i mean if the answer is correct and the player find the different image  it will loop and random again.

Comment: so you need a code to do that?

Comment: if ok sir.. my code won't do the task i need .. i have only limited knowledge about programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok,

first of all, keep a reference to the ImageViews your are using, and use findViewById everytime you go through your loop, because that a waste of time, as it is expensive.

this will give you the views id-3,

```
int vs = imageViews[i]-3;
```

so if you call

```
ImageView ivs = (ImageView) findViewById( vs );
```

ivs it might be null, or a different View than the i-3rd in your list.

This code will show the same randomImage for 3 random ImageViews and set another randomImage form the Other array to the last ImageView

```
Random random = new Random( System.currentTimeMillis() );

ImageView[] imageViews = new ImageView[4];

int[] img = new int[] {R.drawable.img1,R.drawable.img2,R.drawable.img3,R.drawable.img4,
        R.drawable.img5,R.drawable.img6,R.drawable.img7,R.drawable.img8,
        R.drawable.img9,R.drawable.img10};

int [] ansImg = new int[]{R.drawable.aimg1,R.drawable.aimg2,R.drawable.aimg3,R.drawable.aimg4,
    R.drawable.aimg5,R.drawable.aimg6,R.drawable.aimg7,R.drawable.aimg8,
        R.drawable.aimg9,R.drawable.aimg10};

private void allImage() {
     imageViews[0]= (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.A);
     imageViews[1]= (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.B);
     imageViews[2]= (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.C);
     imageViews[3]= (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.D);
}

    public void randomImage(){
    // List<Integer> generated = new ArrayList<Integer>(); i dont get what that is supposed to do?

    int next = random.nextInt( img.length+1 ); // will generate a position from a random image within the img array
    int randomOtherImage = random.nextInt( ansImg.length+1 );
    int differentImage = random.nextInt( imageViews.length+1 );
    for (int i = 0; i < imageViews.length; i++) {
        if (differentImage == i)
            imageViews[i].setImageRessource(ansImg[randomOtherImage]);
        else
            imageViews[i].setImageRessource(ans[next]);
    }
}
```